# How to use MTAudioProcessingTapProcessCallback to modify the pitch of the audio on iOS

Tags: avfoundation, core-audio, audio-processing, core-media

Here is the tapProcess callback. and How to modify the audio's pitch by modifying `bufferListInOut`, also, how to do if I just want to modify the audio in specific `CMTimeRange`

```swift
let tapProcessCallback: MTAudioProcessingTapProcessCallback = { tap,
        numberFrames, flags, bufferListInOut, numberFramesOut, flagsOut in
        var timeRange: CMTimeRange = CMTimeRange.zero
        let status = MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio(tap, numberFrames, bufferListInOut, flagsOut, &timeRange, numberFramesOut)
        if status != noErr {
            print("Failed to get source audio")
            return
        }
        let context = Unmanaged<AudioProcessingTapContext>.fromOpaque(MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap)).takeUnretainedValue()
        let bufferList = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(bufferListInOut)
        
        // then how to modify audio.....
    }
```

I want to process the audio realtime when playback, and can change the audio in specific CMTimeRange

Comment: Which API are you tapping?